# async pipe with angular/ionic/firebase and ngFor

Tags: angular, firebase, asynchronous, ionic-framework, pipe

I am trying to figure out the `async` pipe. For code I have:

In my page:

```
this.distanceList = this.af.list('/distances/' + this.username,
    ref => ref.orderByChild("distance").limitToFirst(20)).valueChanges().map(e => [e]);
```

In my html:

```
<div class ='distance contentone' #distance [@moveList]='moveState'>
   <ion-list class="marginstatus" no-padding>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let item of distanceList|async" no-padding>
        {{ item.username }}
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</div>
```

Only one item row loads and it is blank. I am using firebase so I am not sure if their `Observable` will work directly with the `async` pipe. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You has write .map(e=>[e]). That is: you receive "e" -I suppose it's an array-, and return an array of one element. Why not .map(e=>e)? -really why not remove the map instruction?

Comment: thats what i ended up doing...i originally wanted to add a profile picture property to the item before it gets displayed...would i use map? i tried a few different ways but couldnt get it